# How do I read the properties of a KineticJS Sprite other than X and Y coords?

Tags: sprite, kineticjs

I am new to using **KineticJS** and am using it to develop a simple 2D game which involves sprites, collision detection etc.

I need to access various properties of my **sprite** object (let's call it spriteObj here).

I can get to the sprite coordinates using **spriteObj.getX()** and **spriteObj.getY()** and this works perfectly.

Now I need to also retrieve the other properties of the sprite, such as **height** and **width**, but there does not seem to be a way to do it.  Specifically if I have an **animation** within my sprite, how can I retrieve the current frame and/or the x, y, height, width of that animation frame.

What I really need is something like **spriteObj.getWidth()** and **spriteObj.getHeight()** but these do not exist.  Any suggestions please? I can see nothing on the html5 tutorials page for this ([see here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-sprite-tutorial/%29))

Thanks,
Owen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you are looking for do exist, check the [KineticJS Sprite API](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Sprite.html)

Here is the [KineticJS Sprite Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-sprite-tutorial/)

Here are the functions you asked for:

- [Sprite.getX()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Sprite.html#getX)
- [Sprite.getY()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Sprite.html#getY)
- [Sprite.getWidth()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Sprite.html#getWidth)
- [Sprite.getHeight()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Sprite.html#getHeight)
- [Sprite.getIndex()](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Sprite.html#getIndex)

Based off of that tutorial I added some code to fit your needs, check the `console.log` to see the methods in action. For the width and height, although it is not necessary, you have to specify a width and height property on your **spriteObj** or else it will just return **0**.

```
    var blob = new Kinetic.Sprite({
        x: 250,
        y: 40,
        image: imageObj,
        animation: 'idle',
        animations: animations,
        frameRate: 7,
        index: 0,
        width: 80,
        height: 100
    });
```

And a new button to test the `getIndex()` function:

```
// stop animation
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert(blob.getIndex());
}, false);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/X6LQW/)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I think I see the problem. I saw the properties in the API but they didn't work for me (returned 'undefined').  I think it may be due to the fact I didn't specify width or height in the Sprite obj properties when I initialized it in my code. I left width and height out of the properties and just left them as default.  So to use the getWidth() and getHeight() methods it's critical that width and height are specified in the new Sprite object when initialised.  (For some reason I assumed if left out, they'd default to the image height/width automatically).

Comment: Incidentally the width and height are not specified in the Sprite declaration example in the tutorial, which is probably why I missed it originally!